# What means that kind of declaration in c++?

Tags: c++

What does this kind of declaration mean in c++?

```
CSomething & SOMETHING = m_vSOMETHING[m_iSOMETHING];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a reference variable which is initialized to point to the specified cell in `m_vSOMETHING`

So a declaration of

```
int &reftotable = table[42];
```

Will produce reftotable as a variable which reference cell 42 in the table, similar to what

```
int *pointertocell = &table[42];
```

would do.  In the first case with the reference you can assign reftotable like it was a normal variable

```
reftotable = 37;
```

where in the other case you will have to do

```
*pointertocell = 37;
```

to do the same thing -- that is, in both cases table[42] will contain the value 37 after the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

`SOMETHING` is a reference to a `CSomething` and you are assigning the `m_iSOMETHING`th element of `m_vSOMETHING` to that reference